# Facebook oauth dialog not calling the callback function

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, callback, fb.ui

It appears that the FB.ui method='oauth' has stopped calling our callback function on a production site. Here is our code:

```
FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'oauth',
            client_id: '[outClienID]',
            redirect_uri: '[validRedirect_uri]',
            scope:'email, publish_stream',
            response_type: 'token',
            display: 'popup'
        },
        function(response) {
            FB.getLoginStatus(checkFBConnect, true);
        })
```

I have tried replacing the FB.getLoginStatus with a simple alert and it is never called. When I call FB.getLoginStatus(checkFBConnect, true); manually from a debugging console, the process all works as intended. It's like our function(response) is never called by facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving *redirect_uri* and *response_type* parameter out solves this in canvas/pages applications:

```
        FB.ui({method: 'oauth',
        client_id: fb_app_id,
        state: new Date().getTime().toString(),
        /*
        redirect_uri: location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/' + app_folder + '/oauth',
        response_type: 'token',
        */
        scope: 'email,publish_actions'
    }, callback);
```

On the other hand, if your application isn't meant to run in a canvas/page, then it is true that your callback function won't be called anymore, but you can handle the oauth token directly in your *redirect_uri* callback page.